# Optimising Javascript Object Merge Function

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to optimise the following code block, interms of less code and speed.
It simply merges 2 JavaScript objects into 1. Although it works fine, I'm sure this could be cleaner. Any help would be awesome.

Also it must be done in native JavaScript without using a library such as JQuery etc.

Cheers

```
function mergeObject(obj1, obj2) {
    var output = {};
    if (!obj2) {
        return obj1;
    }
    for (var prop in obj1) {
        if (prop in obj2) {
            output[prop] = obj2[prop];
        } else {
            output[prop] = obj1[prop];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at how other libraries do this.  For example underscore.js: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-78

Comment: are you sure this works? what if you have a property in obj2 that's not in obj1?

Comment: Vic is right, this doesn't merge anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, but note that a property in `a` will be overwritten if it's also in `b`.

```
function(a, b) {
  if (a && b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```